# How to create multiple vertical rows of radio buttons html

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to replicate this interface in a webpage:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iDp1.png)

So far I've tried this:

```html
<form action="">
      <label for="viname1">Source Name 1</label> <input id="viname1" type="radio" name="output1" value="input1">  <input id="ainame1" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput1"><br>
      <label for="viname2">Source Name 2</label> <input id="viname2" type="radio" name="output1" value="input2">  <input id="ainame2" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput2"><br>
      <label for="viname3">Source Name 3</label> <input id="viname3" type="radio" name="output1" value="input3">  <input id="ainame3" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput3"><br>
      <label for="viname4">Source Name 4</label> <input id="viname4" type="radio" name="output1" value="input4">  <input id="ainame4" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput4"><br>
      <label for="viname5">Source Name 5</label> <input id="viname5" type="radio" name="output1" value="input5">  <input id="ainame5" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput5"><br>
      <label for="viname6">Source Name 6</label> <input id="viname6" type="radio" name="output1" value="input6">  <input id="ainame6" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput6"><br>
      <label for="viname7">Source Name 7</label> <input id="viname7" type="radio" name="output1" value="input7">  <input id="ainame7" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput7"><br>
      <label for="viname8">Source Name 8</label> <input id="viname8" type="radio" name="output1" value="input8">  <input id="ainame8" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput8"><br>
      <label for="viname9">None</label> <input id="viname9" type="radio" name="output1" value="input9">  <input id="ainame9" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput9"><br>

    </form>
```

But the radio buttons do not align, I'm not sure how to align them with CSS or any other way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a table, with rows and columns. The cells taking part of a column will be vertically aligned.

```html
<form action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="viname1">Source Name 1</label></td>
      <td><input id="viname1" type="radio" name="output1" value="input1"></td>
      <td><input id="ainame1" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="viname9">None</label></td>
      <td><input id="viname9" type="radio" name="output1" value="input9"></td>
      <td><input id="ainame9" type="radio" name="aoutput1" value="ainput9"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```